chainlink functions. I have tested the code in the "Playground". However, when I call it on the page or on remix, I always get an error
The JAVASCRIPT code is as follows:
···
const _matchid = args[0];
const _extid = args[1];
const _apikey = args[2];
try {
const _url = `https://api.sportmonks.com/v3/football/fixtures/${_extid}`;
const response = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url: _url,
    method: "GET",
    params: {
        api_token: _apikey,
        include: "scores"
    },
});

if (response.error) {
    throw new Error(response.message);
}

const { data } = response;

let _state = 0;
if (data.data.state_id === 5) {
    _state = 1;
}

let _msg = data.data.result_info;
const scores = data.data.scores;
const fullTimeScores = scores.filter(score => score.type_id === 1525);

let homeGoals = 0;
let awayGoals = 0;
for (const score of fullTimeScores) {
    if (score.score.participant === 'home') {
        homeGoals = score.score.goals;
    } else if (score.score.participant === 'away') {
        awayGoals = score.score.goals;
    }
}

let _result = 0;
if (homeGoals > awayGoals) {
    _result = 1;
} else if (homeGoals === awayGoals) {
    _result = 2;
} else if (homeGoals < awayGoals) {
    _result = 3;
}

let resultobj = {
    IsOk: true, 
    MatchId: _matchid, 
    ExtId: _extid, 
    State: _state, 
    Result: _result, 
    Msg: _msg
};

return Functions.encodeString(JSON.stringify(resultobj));
} catch (error) {
console.info(error);
return Functions.encodeString(JSON.stringify({ 
    IsOk: false, 
    MatchId: _matchid, 
    ExtId: _extid, 
    State: 3, 
    Result: 0, 
    Msg: error 
}));
}

···

My method in the contract is this:
function sendRequest(
    string[] calldata args
) external returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(config.Source);
  
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args);
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            config.SubscriptionId,
            config.GasLimit,
            config.DonId
        );

    return s_lastRequestId;
}

I have tested the code in the "Playground"，However, using the same parameters, whether calling directly on the page or in remix, an error is prompted, and no error message is seen

Can you share the corresponding source script, the way you're using in your contract ?
